# how to fix error about BERT?just confuse me few days

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, bert-language-model

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:/desk/bert-master333/bert-master/run_classifier.py", line 1024, in <module>
    tf.app.run()

  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)

  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))

  File "D:/desk/bert-master333/bert-master/run_classifier.py", line 885, in main
    train_examples = processor.get_train_examples(FLAGS.data_dir)

  File "D:/desk/bert-master333/bert-master/run_classifier.py", line 380, in get_train_examples
    self._read_tsv(os.path.join(data_dir, "train.csv")), "train")

  File "D:/desk/bert-master333/bert-master/run_classifier.py", line 410, in _create_examples
    label = tokenization.convert_to_unicode(line[1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
class limengnanProcessor(DataProcessor):

def get_train_examples(self, data_dir):
    return self._create_examples(
        self._read_tsv(os.path.join(data_dir, "train.csv")), "train")

def get_dev_examples(self, data_dir):
    return self._create_examples(
        self._read_tsv(os.path.join(data_dir, "dev.csv")), "dev")

def get_test_examples(self, data_dir):
    return self._create_examples(
        self._read_tsv(os.path.join(data_dir, "test.csv")), "test")

def get_labels(self):
    return ['0','1']

def _read_tsv(cls, input_file, quotechar=None):
    with tf.gfile.Open(input_file, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="&", quotechar=quotechar)
        lines = []
        for line in reader:
            lines.append(line)
        return lines

def _create_examples(self, lines, set_type):
    examples = []
    for (i, line) in enumerate(lines):
        guid = "%s-%s" % (set_type, i)
        if set_type == "test":
            text_a = tokenization.convert_to_unicode(line[0])
            label = "0"
        else:
            text_a = tokenization.convert_to_unicode(line[0])
            label = tokenization.convert_to_unicode(line[1])
        if label not in ['0','1']:
            continue

        examples.append(
            InputExample(guid=guid, text_a=text_a, text_b=None, label=label))
    return examples
```

Comment: error shows problem with `list index out of range` in line  `label = tokenization.convert_to_unicode(line[1])` and there is index `[1]` - so first check what you have in `print( line )` because it seems it is empty or has only one element but you expect two elements. So your problem can be wrong data in file. Or maybe you read it in wrong way. Do you really use `&` as delimiter in file? Usually CSV uses `,` - eventually `;`

Comment: shorter: `lines = list(reader)`